AWS NodeJS Elastic Beanstalk CORs Issue
I have a NodeJS Application with Cors policy configured in index.js, as shown below... The application is hosted in AWS Elastic Beanstalk. Although CORs have been configured, the issue I am facing is that after successful login via the frontend, I now receive some CORs. The application was working great for well over a month or two. I verified my EC2, my DNS, and my Load Balancer and just cannot seem to locate the issue. Any pointers or advice will be greatly appreciated!
require('dotenv').config();
const AWS_S3_Bucket_Handler = require('./config/aws/s3Handler');
const jsonHandler = require('./functions/jsonHandler');
const host = process.env.HOST;
const port = process.env.PORT;
const prodStatus = process.env.IN_PROD
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const cors = require('cors');
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');

if (prodStatus === "true") {
  jsonHandler.testJson();
  AWS_S3_Bucket_Handler.importBackupFromS3();
}

app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());
app.use(cookieParser());

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send("The server is running successfully. <br/>The server is running on port " + port + "... <br/>The server url is " + host + "...")
});

const userRoute = require('./routes/User');
app.use('/user', userRoute);

const adminRoute = require('./routes/Admin');
app.use('/admin', adminRoute);

const triviaRoute = require('./routes/Trivia');
app.use('/trivia', triviaRoute);

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log("Server running on port " + port + "...");
});


CORs Error Messages:
GET https://www.catchingsouls.net/root.admin/env.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://server.catchingsouls.net/admin/adminTool/TriviaRetrieval' from origin 'https://www.catchingsouls.net' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
POST https://server.catchingsouls.net/admin/adminTool/TriviaRetrieval net::ERR_FAILED 403 (Forbidden)

I managed to locate my issue. I navigated to AWS WAF to check my firewall settings and found out that I had a rule on that started to block me for some reason... The rule is called "Admin protection". Once I removed this, everything loaded fine, but I will review the possible cause for this rule issue...
